# Ошибка «Доступ запрещён» после задания пустого пароля в phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Зашёл я в PHPMyAmin — было всё нормально.

Решил прямо там же сделать доступ к аккаунту без пароля, то есть убрал пароль. Дальше, чтобы проверить, что и как, я сделал логаут и решил снова зайти, Но теперь он меня выдаёт ошибку:

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Посмотрел иностранные форумы и индусов на ютубе и понял, что ничего не понял. Пытался сам всё исправить: в config поставил пароль `123` и сделал `passwordrequired = true`, но всё равно ничего не работает:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Как быть?

Comment: пароль mysql сбросьте

Comment: Заходи через консоль и ставь пароль

Comment: поподробнее можно? я на винде 7 если что

Comment: как мне это сделать

Comment: http://linux.bolden.ru/mysql-password-change/

Comment: http://saradmin.ru/?p=926

Comment: это на винде тоже работает?

Comment: Да тоже работает

Comment: что за консоль? в обычной cmd если ввожу всё это  у меня ошибки

Comment: у вас какой сервер? openServer, Denwer? Переходите в папку, там есть данные запуска сервера, там находите mysql.exe вроде, его запускаете с помощью cmd

Comment: у меня апач стоит. Ничего не выходит, короче либо я даун, либо даун

Comment: ну, моя cmd консоль не понимает этих запросов

Comment: Проверь переменные окружения прописан ли путь к каталогу где лежит mysql

Comment: апач это сервер htpd, он не имеет отношения к myql. Думаю вам нужно всё удалить, и заново установить))

Comment: не нужно, всё работало прекрасно один час назад. Но потом я сбросил пароль из админки пхпмайадмин и всё перестало работать

Comment: Час назад или же секунду назад, это нечего не меняет, вам нужно найти директорию сервера myql, после чего вы сможете запустить процесс сброс пароля

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо сделать следующее:

1. Заходите в папку с `bin` (у меня `.../mysql/mysql sever 5.7/bin`).
2. С зажатой клавишей <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> кликаете правой кнопкой в любое свободное место в папке.

   1. Дальше жмёте «Открыть окно команд».
3. В консоли пишете: `mysqladmin.exe -u root -p password`

   1. Консоль потребует от вас пароль, вы его введёте, и после он попросит от вас новый пароль.
4. Работает для тех, кто уже знает свой пароль, но всё равно не может войти в phpmyadmin (я не исключение). Те, кто не знает пароль, можете узнать его в `config.ini.php` (я не помню точно, где он расположен, но в этом файле будет строка с вашим паролем и логином).
5. Заходим в PHPMyAdmin и работаем как обычно.

Answer (score 0):

В консоли заходишь в MySQL:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

В БД от которой потерял пароль:

```
use tvoyabaza
```

и меняешь пароль на `vasya`, имя пользователя `vasya`

```
UPDATE sys_user SET passwort = md5('vasya') WHERE username = 'vasya';
```